# IIS 8 : "information about PHP cannot be obtained due to invalid IIS configuration"

Tags: php, iis, iis-8

See error below.

How to resolve?

[image]

Comment: PHP Manager has been maintained for years, and PHP 5.6 is also dying. You probably should move on to newer bits.

Comment: @LexLi You mean PHP Manager has _not_ been maintained?  I know 5.6 is dying. It is an old system running forums.

Comment: I wish people would stop making comments about old versions of PHP or MySQL or whatever, as if everybody has the option to just choose whichever version they want.  Sometimes we don't have options, so if the question is about an old version, it's not helpful to say we should use a newer version.

Answer (score 1):

solved

We updated PHP, with a simple xcopy.

But the result was that php.ini was missing from "C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.6\"

We put it there, did an iisreset, and php is back in gear!

Comment: Odd, since the PHP install instructions recommend putting it in C:/PHP, but you're right, as soon as I moved it into c:/program files (x86)/php/v5.6 IIS was able to find it.  And now that I have a valid PHP config, I am able to register another PHP version at whatever path I want, but it seems that first one needs to be in a specific location.